# Disconnected view from View in interface builder iOS

Tags: xcode, xib

I am working on my signInViewController.xib file and I accidentally disconnected the view from View in files owner.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you accidentally disconnected the view from the *View Controller*, yes?

If that's the case, control drag from the View Controller object to your view and one of the connections you can make is the *View* one.

If you actually mean that the File Owner for the XIB is no longer the View Controller, go to the Attributes Inspector for the File Owner and set the "Custom Class" attribute to the name of your View Controller class.

A nice visual description of the architecture [is in this Apple documentation, in Figure 2-4](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html).

Hope this info helps!